# integrating linkedin login with angularjs application

Tags: angularjs, linkedin-api

I am new to angular js .I would like to know the procedure to get api key and integrating linked in sign in ,sign up with angularjs application.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LinkedIn SDK to handle authorisation and sing up or sing off users.

Documentation: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/getting-started-js-sdk

1. You have to initial SDK. You will need to create an app in your LinkedIn Developer panel. Then you get an API Key there.

Then in your app you have to create a service that will call LinkedIn API.

Something like this:

```js
export class LinkedIn {
    constructor($q, $window) {
        'ngInject';

        this.$q = $q;
        this.$window = $window;
    };

    get() {
        let doc = this.$window.document;
        let script = doc.createElement('script');
        let deferred = this.$q.defer();

        script.src = 'http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js';

        script.innerHTML = [
            'api_key: ' + YOUR_API_KEY,
            'authorize: ' + 'true',
            'lang: ' + 'en-US',
            'onLoad: onLinkedInApiLoad',
            'scope: ' + YOUR_APP_SCOPE
        ].join('\n');
        
        this.$window.onLinkedInApiLoad = () => {
            deferred.resolve(this.$window.IN);
        };
        
        doc.body.appendChild(script);

        return deferred.promise;
    };
}
```

2. Next you need to decide where and when you want to initial this call. You can do that in `.run` block or made some middleware to handle it. After that you will receive LinkedIn API object.
3. When you have got your LinkedIn API object you can request  authorisation, check if user has been already logged in and etc. Options are describe in documentation. You can authorise user calling `IN.User.authorize(handler || angular.noop)` or logout `IN.User.logout(handler || angular.noop)`
4. There is also options to do a callback on Event where user log in or log out for example:

`IN.Event.on(IN, eventName, callback, callbackScope, extraData);`
`IN.Event.onOnce(IN, eventName, callback, callbackScope, extraData);`

Comment: What you mean service in angularjs? I've already gave you a one service that handle SDK call.

Comment: i guess your service is in angular2 .. i need in angular1

Comment: It's Angular 1. Don't worry. If you are not using ES6 and not feel comfortable using classes so grab logic from my service and put into yours. Don't worry about constructor just inject necessary dependencies into your service. Then you can return `.get()` method to gain access to logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular module for linkedIn authentication. [angular-social-login](https://github.com/heresy/angularjs-social-login)

Comment: Any better way without using this?

Comment: @SanjanaPrasad: You can check the docs here. https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2# if you dont prefer any plugins.

Comment: You can also check out the js file for implementation. https://github.com/jacobwarduk/ng-linkedin-oauth